# Save under a filename once, and then save under same filename without dialog popping up asking for filename?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I wish to avoid popping up the dialog for each save attempt and choose a filename once, and save without asking for filename after?

Ideally the app should show the dialog once, save the filename. Then encapsulate code saving data into a method, make the filename visible to it, and call it when needed.

Not sure how to do this.

```
private void SaveData() //Figure out how to remeber previous save name
    { 
        string taxpayerLine;
        string taxpayerFile;
        SaveFileDialog taxpayerFileChooser;
        StreamWriter fileWriter;
        taxpayerFileChooser = new SaveFileDialog();
        taxpayerFileChooser.Filter = "All text files|*.txt";

        if (taxpayerFileChooser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            taxpayerFile = taxpayerFileChooser.FileName;
            taxpayerFileChooser.Dispose();

            fileWriter = new StreamWriter(taxpayerFile, true);

            foreach (Taxpayer txp in taxpayerBindingSource)
            {
                taxpayerLine = txp.Display(","); 
                fileWriter.WriteLine(taxpayerLine);
            }

            fileWriter.Close();
            fileWriter.Dispose();  //Destructor

            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved to: "
                + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(taxpayerFile));
```

Comment: Just put the `taxpayerfile` variable in the class and before showing the `SaveFileDialog`, check if it already has a value

Comment: If you want this to be saved across session just use the settings file and read/write from/to it